# When I run an ORACLE 12c report after reports have not run for a while, the report waits for 6 minutes before it decides to do anything

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oraclereports

We have just converted an 11g application to 12c. While testing, I can see that running a report will take odiously long if I haven't run a report for a while, but after that, reports run in their normal time. The reports servlet just says "The report is opening to run" and the trace file has a 6-minute gap in its entries, notably after stating it is checking access to DESNAME. If the report is being run in batch, it will still have a 6-minute wait, finish ok but include an ORA-03113 message ('End of file on communication channel') in its report servlet message.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Our MW expert consulted the oracle and changed the engine class line in rwserver.conf so that engLife was changed from "50" to "30" and minEngine was changed from "1" to "0.
This fixed the issue.